# Prove that $f=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

Let $a_{1},b_{1},...a_{n},b_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$ so that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\sin(x+b_{k})$ verifies $f(u)=f(v)=0,$ for two real numbers $u,v$, with $u-v\neq k\pi ,k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Prove that $f(x)=0,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

After some calculation, I obtained that $f\left ( \frac{u+v}{2} \right )=0$ and $f'\left ( \frac{u+v}{2} \right )=0$, but these results didn't help me at all so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\cdot \sin(x+b_{k}) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}h_{k}\right) \sin(x) + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}g_{k}\right) \cos(x) = A_k\sin(x) + B_k\cos(x).$$

It is obvious that having

$$
\begin{cases}
A_k\sin(v) + B_k\cos(v) = 0,\\
A_k\sin(u) + B_k\cos(u) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

we will proceed with notion

$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(v) & \cos(v),\\
\sin(u) & \cos(u).
\end{bmatrix} = \sin(v)\cos(u) - \cos(v)\sin(u) = \sin(v-u) \ne \sin(\pi n)
= 0,$$
so we necessarily have $A_k = B_k = 0$, as the system has only one trivial solution due to $\det \ne 0$.

Answer (score 3):

You obtained $f\left ( \frac{u+v}{2} \right )=0$. By induction, you'll be able to prove that $f(x)=0$ for $x \in \{u+\frac{k}{2^n}(v-u) \ ; \ (k, n) \in \mathbb N^2, \ 0\le k\le 2^n\}=S(u,v)$.

As $S(u,v)$ is dense in $[u,v]$ and $f$ continuous on that interval, $f$ vanishes on $[u,v]$.

You can then reproduce that proof taking $v=u+2 k \pi$ to conclude that $f $ vanishes at all the reals.